# NestJS TypeORM repository save function is doing insert instead of update

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have following datamodel

[image: datamodel]

Following entities are added
domain.entity.ts

```
import { OneToMany, PrimaryColumn, Relation } from 'typeorm';   
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  VersionColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { DomainType } from '../enum/enums';
import { Label } from './label.entity';

@Entity()
export class Domain {
  @PrimaryColumn('varchar', { length: 30 })
  name: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 100 })
  description: string;

  @Column({ default: DomainType.STRING })
  type: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 254, default: '' })
  inputmask: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 254, default: '' })
  displayMask: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  creationDate: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  lastUpdateDate: Date;

  @VersionColumn()
  version: number;

  @OneToMany(() => Label, (label) => label.name, { cascade: ['remove'] })
  metadata: Relation<Label>;
  labels: Label[];
}
```

label.entity.ts

```
import { JoinColumn, ManyToOne, OneToMany, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  VersionColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Domain } from './domain.entity';
import { LabelI18n } from './labelI18n.entity';

@Entity()
export class Label {
  @PrimaryColumn('varchar', { length: 30 })
  @ManyToOne(() => Domain)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'name', referencedColumnName: 'name' }) // koppel kolom 'name' aan kolom name uit tabel domain
  name: string;

  @PrimaryColumn('varchar', { length: 30 })
  label: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 20 })
  shortDescription: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  longDescription: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  creationDate: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  lastUpdateDate: Date;

  @VersionColumn()
  version: number;

  @OneToMany(() => LabelI18n, (labelI18n) => labelI18n.name, {
    cascade: ['remove'],
  })
  labelsI18n: LabelI18n[];
}
```

labelI18n.entity.ts

```
import { JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  VersionColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Label } from './label.entity';

@Entity()
export class LabelI18n {
  @PrimaryColumn('varchar', { length: 30 })
  @ManyToOne(() => Label)
  @JoinColumn([
    { name: 'name', referencedColumnName: 'name' },
    { name: 'label', referencedColumnName: 'label' },
  ])
  name: string;

  @PrimaryColumn('varchar', { length: 30 })
  label: string;

  @PrimaryColumn('varchar', { length: 10 })
  language: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 20 })
  shortDescription: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  longDescription: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  creationDate: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  lastUpdateDate: Date;

  @VersionColumn()
  version: number;
}
```

I use postgress, the tables are correct created and the needed primary keys and foreign keys are added .

All crud functions I have created works for the domain table, for the label table all works except the update function, I use following code in the update function (I add the repositories in the constructor of my service class), only methods related to the label table are included in the snippet

```
@Injectable()
export class DomainPrivateService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Domain)
    private readonly domainRepository: Repository<Domain>,
    @InjectRepository(Label)
    private readonly labelRepository: Repository<Label>,
    @InjectRepository(LabelI18n)
    private readonly labelI18nRepository: Repository<LabelI18n>,
  ) {}

  private async checkContraintsLabel(name: string, labelId: string) {
    if (name !== undefined && labelId !== undefined) {
      const label = await this.labelRepository.findOne({
        where: { name: name, label: labelId },
      });
      if (label) {
        throw new BadRequestException('Duplicate key');
      }
    }
  }

  // Label
  async getLabel(name: string, labelId: string) {
    const label = await this.labelRepository.findOne({
      where: { name: name, label: labelId },
    });
    if (!label) {
      throw new NotFoundException(
        'Label ' + name + '/' + labelId + ' not found.',
      );
    }
    return label;
  }

  async createLabel(
    name: string,
    labelId: string,
    createLabelDto: CreateLabelDto,
  ) {
    await this.checkContraintsLabel(name, labelId);
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    const domain = await this.getDomain(name);
    const label = this.labelRepository.create(createLabelDto);
    label.name = name;
    label.label = labelId;
    try {
      await this.labelRepository.save(label);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException(error);
    }
    return label;
  }

  async updateLabel(
    name: string,
    labelId: string,
    updateLabelDto: UpdateLabelDto,
  ) {
    console.log('updateLabel ');
    const label = await this.labelRepository.preload({
      name: name,
      label: labelId,
      ...updateLabelDto,
    });

    if (!label) {
      throw new NotFoundException(
        'Label ' + name + '/' + labelId + ' not found.',
      );
    }

    return await this.labelRepository.save(label);
  }

  async deleteLabel(name: string, labelId: string) {
    const label = await this.getLabel(name, labelId);

    await this.labelRepository.remove(label);
  }

}
```

when I do a patch request for an update of an existing label and log the sql statements, I get the following output for the preload method

```
query: SELECT "Label"."name" AS "Label_name", "Label"."label" AS "Label_label", "Label"."shortDescription" AS "Label_shortDescription", "Label"."longDescription" AS "Label_longDescription", "Label"."creationDate" AS "Label_creationDate", "Label"."lastUpdateDate" AS "Label_lastUpdateDate", "Label"."version" AS "Label_version" FROM "label" "Label" WHERE ((("Label"."name" = $1 AND "Label"."label" = $2))) -- PARAMETERS: ["dsca10","label2"]
query: SELECT "Domain"."name" AS "Domain_name", "Domain"."description" AS "Domain_description", "Domain"."type" AS "Domain_type", "Domain"."inputmask" AS "Domain_inputmask", "Domain"."displayMask" AS "Domain_displayMask", "Domain"."creationDate" AS "Domain_creationDate", "Domain"."lastUpdateDate" AS "Domain_lastUpdateDate", "Domain"."version" AS "Domain_version" FROM "domain" "Domain" WHERE "Domain"."name" IN ($1) -- PARAMETERS: [null]
```

The first statement is the check in the label table with key 'dsca10', 'label2', this is a correct check and this record exists
the second statement is the check in the domain table with key 'null', this is not correct and the key must be 'dsca10', is this the reason why the save method decides to do an insert instead of an update?

Output for the save method

```
query: SELECT "Label"."name" AS "Label_name", "Label"."label" AS "Label_label", "Label"."shortDescription" AS "Label_shortDescription", "Label"."longDescription" AS "Label_longDescription", "Label"."creationDate" AS "Label_creationDate", "Label"."lastUpdateDate" AS "Label_lastUpdateDate", "Label"."version" AS "Label_version" FROM "label" "Label" WHERE ((("Label"."name" = $1 AND "Label"."label" = $2))) -- PARAMETERS: ["dsca10","label2"]
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO "label"("name", "label", "shortDescription", "longDescription", "creationDate", "lastUpdateDate", "version") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "creationDate", "lastUpdateDate", "version" -- PARAMETERS: ["dsca10","label2","korte omschrijving2","lange omschrijving2","2023-04-05T19:44:50.176Z","2023-04-05T19:44:50.176Z",1]
query failed: INSERT INTO "label"("name", "label", "shortDescription", "longDescription", "creationDate", "lastUpdateDate", "version") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "creationDate", "lastUpdateDate", "version" -- PARAMETERS: ["dsca10","label2","korte omschrijving2","lange omschrijving2","2023-04-05T19:44:50.176Z","2023-04-05T19:44:50.176Z",1]
error: error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_1dedf7625a4373e6cc875df760e"
query: ROLLBACK
[Nest] 298291  - 06/04/2023 10:37:51   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_1dedf7625a4373e6cc875df760e"
QueryFailedError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_1dedf7625a4373e6cc875df760e"
    at PostgresQueryRunner.query (/data-mirror/development/mwsapp/src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:299:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at InsertQueryBuilder.execute (/data-mirror/development/mwsapp/src/query-builder/InsertQueryBuilder.ts:163:33)
    at SubjectExecutor.executeInsertOperations (/data-mirror/development/mwsapp/src/persistence/SubjectExecutor.ts:428:42)
    at SubjectExecutor.execute (/data-mirror/development/mwsapp/src/persistence/SubjectExecutor.ts:137:9)
    at EntityPersistExecutor.execute (/data-mirror/development/mwsapp/src/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.ts:197:21)
    at DomainPrivateService.updateLabel (/data-mirror/development/mwsapp/src/mwsapp/domain/domain.private.service.ts:219:12)
    at /data-mirror/development/mwsapp/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at /data-mirror/development/mwsapp/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

The save method is doing an insert where an update is expected. Because of the insert a duplicate error is returned from the database (PK_1dedf7625a4373e6cc875df760e is the primary key check for table label).

Is there something wrong in my code? I use nestjs 9 with typeORM 0.3.12

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Upsert` method for similar case
Example:

```
await this.connection.getRepository(NetworkPermissionsEntity).upsert(
    {
      networkId,
      permissions: permissions.permissions,
    },
    {
      conflictPaths: ['networkId'],
      skipUpdateIfNoValuesChanged: true,
    },
  );
```

This will work like

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
```

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
UPDATE t1 SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;

Comment: technically this works, I don't get an error but the data is not correctly updated.

When I use the save method on the domain table (here works the save method) I get following update statement in the logging

query: START TRANSACTION
query: UPDATE "domain" SET "description" = $1, "version" = "version" + 1, "lastUpdateDate" = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE "name" IN ($2) RETURNING "lastUpdateDate", "version" -- PARAMETERS: ["string with length 10 characters.","dsca10"]
query: COMMIT

The update statement contains logic for the special fields (lastUpdateDate & version)

Comment: But with the upsert

   return await this.labelRepository.upsert(label, {
      conflictPaths: ['name', 'label'],
      skipUpdateIfNoValuesChanged: true,
    });

these column were not updated, also the return value is not of type label

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work properly might be that you have too many `@PrimaryColumns` in your entities, and also your relations seem to be incorrect. Try using one `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn`.

If you need some fields to be unique, you can use `@Column({ unique: true })` for a column or `@Unique(['name', 'label'])` ([link](https://typeorm.io/decorator-reference#unique)) for an entity if it should be a unique set of fields.

```js
@Entity()
export class Domain {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column("varchar", { length: 30, unque: true })
    name: string;

    // ...

    // Not label.name but label.domain
    @OneToMany(() => Label, (label) => label.domain, { cascade: ["remove"] })
    labels: Label[];
}
```

```js
@Entity()
@Unique(['name', 'label'])
export class Label {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column("varchar", { length: 30 })
    name: string;

    @Column("varchar", { length: 30 })
    label: string;

    // ...

    @OneToMany(() => LabelI18n, (labelI18n) => labelI18n.baseLabel, {
        cascade: ["remove"],
    })
    labelsI18n: LabelI18n[];

    // Not domain.name but domain.labels
    @ManyToOne(() => Domain, (domain) => domain.labels)
    domain: Domain;
}
```

It's better to have only primary field in `preload` options

```js
const label = await this.labelRepository.preload({ id });
```